# Escaping a hash in a parent ID for elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

We were having some issues where our queries weren't returning items with specific version IDs using ElasticSearch 2.3.  After some investigation, it looks like our current elasticsearch query is not behaving when there is a '#' in the version ID.

The query I am trying to perform is something like the following:

```
{
    "query": {
        "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
                "terms": {
                    "_parent": [
                        "faro-deployments-webservice-infrastructure|#abc123",
                        "faro-deployments-webservice-infrastructure|xyz321"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine but excludes any results where the parent ID has a '#' character in it.
I can't seem to find it again, but I recall reading somewhere that # has a specific meaning in this context.  I have tried a variety of ways to attempt to escape the #, is there a way to support versions with a # character in it for this or perform a similar query with similar results?

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work for me.  I changed the query to do something similar and did not use the "_parent" field.

```
{
    "query": {
        "has_parent": {
            "type": "deck", 
            "query": {
                "constant_score": {
                    "filter": {
                        "terms": {
                            "_id": [
                                "faro-deployments-webservice-infrastructure|#abc123",
                                "faro-deployments-webservice-infrastructure|xyz321"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```